# Repairing cracked double-hung window pane

Tags: windows, glass

This double-hung window pane is cracked and I would like to repair it.

[image]

I thought the easiest would be to reorder the whole pane from the manufacturer but the window bears no identification. Should I invest my time in calling glass shops to see if they can extricate this glass and replace it? Can that be done without ruining the pane frame?

Comment: I would think calling a glass company would be your best bet.

Comment: what other options do you realistically have?

Comment: Can the top window be removed? Some can be pushed sideways, against a spring resistance, and come out for cleaning. Then take it to a glass repair shop, where the pane can be cut to exact size.  Needless to say, take care to wear heavy gloves going up arm, lest to torsion push out jagged pieces of glass.

Comment: If it's single-pane glass, replacement is trivial assuming you can get the sash out, and merely annoying if you need to do it from a ladder. Sealed double-glazing is rather more annoying to source, as you can't just have a sheet cut to size at the hardware store, and the methods of holding it in place also differ from the simple "glazing points and putty" most single-pane is held in with. This looks like it might be double-glazing, but hard to be certain.

Comment: If you are going to repair it you have to uninstall it first, for that look under and on top the windows frames (on the horizontal bar. There you should see the metal hardware holding it in place. Take a picture and publish so we can help you further.

Comment: double glass, pane removable

Comment: Then: Remove, measure 3 times, replace broken one to keep the birds out, order replacement, wait, get it, remove, replace. Or tape something else to the frame if you want to take the broken unit to a glass shop so they can measure it 3 times...

Comment: Let the glass guys measure thrice. That way, it’s on them if the fit is wrong. A sealed unit this size isn’t crazy expensive, but it isn’t cheap either. They’ll also be well positioned to say yes or no to replacement, though the answer is almost always yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black/silver stripe we can see at the left makes me think it might be a double-glazed unit, albeit a skinny one. The spread of visible damage from the cracks makes me think at least one surface is laminated.

You can order sealed unit double-glazing in any size, width by height by thickness, from any glazier. If these are anything like standard uPVC frames, the inside should have removable trim/retainers which are reasonably easy to remove. If it is a laminated pane, you would be best to take it to the glazier so they can match it with the new pane - or call them out. If you need to remove the trim to measure, you can just push a couple of them back in the meantime whilst you wait for the new pane to arrive.

Here's a particularly scruffy example from my workroom. The two trim pieces outlined in red just unclip - requires a little effort & two levers - and the entire glazed unit will then just lift out - they're not held in by adhesive or similar, just by the retaining trim. They clip back in afterwards.

*Just to note that, contrary to several comments, you don't need to remove the frame to do this, just the trim.*

Also, measurement is not vital to the absolute mm. These frames tend to have about 10-15mm overall play in the trim covering & you can shim underneath to bring the inside aluminium up to flush. Of course, you want to be as accurate as possible, not 15mm out, but don't go 'tight', leave a tad for expansion. Remove the trim before measuring so you can see how the installers measured it.

[image]

Comment: You make it sound so easy - to extract and re-fit. It's not.

Comment: I did it just last year - it's not rocket science, it's plug & play. ;)